# Combining 5V and 3.3V SPI

Tags: spi, level-shifting, logic-level

On a current project I need to interface several SPI slaves to an ATSAMS70 MCU. The MCU, and some slaves, are operating at 3.3V logic levels. Other slaves need to operate at 5V, so I need a level shifting IC that will allow SPI signals to flow between 3.3V and 5V.

In the first iteration of a prototype I've used two SN74LXCH8T245 - one handling 3.3V to 5V conversion and the other handling 5V to 3.3V.

My problem is that a floating input (like when no slaves are connected on the 5V side) is clamped low and thereby clamping the entire MISO line low. That obviously won't work. So, my question to you all is: Is there an alternative to the SN74LXCH8T245 that will allow the described functionality? I'm quite space constrained, so I'd prefer a part with the same or smaller footprint. It would be preferable if a suggested alternative isn't in perpetual short supply - all the alternatives I've ever worked with are currently impossible to acquire.

Current schematic:
[image: Current schematic]

Comment: what data rates do you use?

Comment: Asking for a specific part is against this stackexchanges rules -- the rational being that an answers based on products will age out.  As far as "it would be preferable if a suggested alternative isn't in perpetual short supply" -- welcome to the year 2022.  I don't think there's any part you could choose that won't be subject to the supply chain weirdness that's currently plaguing the world.

Comment: Jens: 10 Mhz SPI.
TimWescott: Ok. I must've missed that rule - it makes sense though. Maybe a suggestion of a product line or family? I agree that supply chain issues are a part of 2022-electronics-life, but some manufacturers are "better" than others at actually supplying parts...

Comment: The SN74LXCH8T245 you are already using should work but you might be using it wrong. Please add a schematic.

Comment: Please add a circuit diagram to show what you are trying to do.

Comment: Do the inputs of the slaves on the 5V side directly accept 3.3V signals from the MCU or do you need level shifting in this direction as well?

Comment: Peter: I've added a simplified version of the current schematic.

Comment: You can't connect two outputs together and expect it to work. Only one device can drive the MISO node at one given time. One driving high and one driving low will fail to work.

Comment: Jens: No. 5V side needs to be at 5V level...

Comment: Justme: That was what I was thinking while drawing up the simplified schematic... Maybe pass the chip selects through an OR gate and use that to drive the OE?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you need is a level shifter with with an output enable input. With the OE pin deasserted, all of the outputs are tri-stated. If you have a level shifter for each target device with 5V I/O, you could drive the OE pin with the target select (assuming proper polarity). If you're sharing the level shifter with several target devices, you'll need to generate the logical OR of the target selects, perhaps with an additional GPIO.

It is possible for chips to detect floating input (using internal hi-valued pull-up and pull-down resistors so that a hi-Z input will float to Vio/2) so there may also be level shifters that autodetect hi-Z input, but I didn't see any in a quirk search.

Search for "SPI level shifters" to see what is available.

Comment: The level shifter used already has an OE pin, it is just not used as OE.

Comment: @Justme The schematic was edited in after I answered so I missed that. However, it appears to be negative logic (/OE) so it cannot be driver by the target select signal directly.